# Смена картинки по клику с помощью метода attr()

Tags: javascript

Всем доброго дня.

Есть такой скрипт:
Необходимо сделать смену картинок по клику. Нашла в сети пример и написала код по нему. У меня он не работает и в консоли выводит ошибку. Скажите пожалуйста как можно исправить код? Для более лучшего понимания поясню - `.slide-225` - мой класс картинки, и `src` - пути изображений которые я пытаюсь заменить. Буду рада любому замечанию и совету:)

```
$(".slide-225").bind("click", function() {
  var src = ($(this).attr('src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Mirdif-2-960x640.jpg"') === "Mirdif-2-960x640.jpg") ? "Mirdif-full-960x640.jpg" : "Mirdif-2-960x640.jpg";
  $(this).attr('src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Mirdif-2-960x640.jpg"', src);
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы не правильно получаете и записываете атрибут.

Для получения используется запись такого типа: `$(element).attr(attribute);`
Для назначения используется запись такого типа: `$(element).attr(attribute, value);`

В любом случае, название атрибута и его значение указывается в кавычках, если конечно, вы не указываете название атрибута или его значение переменной или каким-то вычислениями в JS

Исправленная версия:

```
$(".slide-225").bind("click", function() {
  var src = $(this).attr('src') ? "Mirdif-full-960x640.jpg" : "Mirdif-2-960x640.jpg";
  $(this).attr('src', src);
});
```

Comment: @Webdev96 если данный ответ является решением вашего вопроса, следует отметить его как правильный.